# need output to txt file instead of json object

Tags: php, json, curl

Is this code convertible to print it's results to a txt file, instead of to a JSON / curl object? We are trying to debug a specific sku and we want to see the output of the long query which precedes this snippet:

```
     foreach($group_sets AS $group_set) {
        $bulk_json .= '{ "index" : { "_id" : "'.$group_set['our_sku'].'" } }'.PHP_EOL;
        $bulk_json .= json_encode($group_set).PHP_EOL;   
     }  
     foreach($remove_skus AS $sku) {
        $bulk_json .= '{ "delete" : { "_id" : "'.$sku.'" } }'.PHP_EOL;           
     }
     print "processing batch, batch count: ".$batch_cnt.PHP_EOL;
     send_to_elastic($bulk_json);
     $bulk_json = ""; 
     $batch_cnt = 0;
     $batch_sku_list = array();
  }
}
 if(!empty($bulk_json)) {
  send_to_elastic($bulk_json);
  $bulk_json = ""; 
}

print PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."DONE".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

function send_to_elastic($bulk_json) {
     $url = "https://ada64ff1913a4b.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243/us/product/_bulk";


     $curl = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "MyName:MyPassword");
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bulk_json);

     echo "uploading batch to elastic-cloud... ";
     $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
     $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
     //if ( $status != 201 ) {
     //   print("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
     //}
     curl_close($curl);
     echo "done".PHP_EOL;
```

Here is my modified code, it doesnt write to the file though so obviously I have something screwed up...

```
         foreach($group_sets AS $group_set) {
        $bulk_json .= '{ "index" : { "_id" : "'.$group_set['my_sku'].'" } }'.PHP_EOL;
        $bulk_json .= json_encode($group_set).PHP_EOL;   
     }  
     foreach($remove_skus AS $sku) {
        $bulk_json .= '{ "delete" : { "_id" : "'.$sku.'" } }'.PHP_EOL;           
     }
     print "processing batch, batch count: ".$batch_cnt.PHP_EOL;
     //send_to_elastic($bulk_json);
     file_put_contents('searchresults.txt', $bulk_json);
     $bulk_json = ""; 
     $batch_cnt = 0;
     $batch_sku_list = array();
  }
}
if(!empty($bulk_json)) {
   //send_to_elastic($bulk_json);
   file_put_contents('searchresults.txt', $bulk_json);
   $bulk_json = ""; 
}

print PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."DONE".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

//function send_to_elastic($bulk_json) {
      //$url = "https://ada64ff1913a4b16us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243/qm/product/_bulk";
      //$curl = curl_init($url);
      //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
     //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "MyUser:MyPW");
     //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bulk_json);

     //echo "uploading batch to elastic-cloud... ";
     //$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
     //$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     //$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
     //if ( $status != 201 ) {
     //   print("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
     //}
     //curl_close($curl);
     echo "done".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Never build JSON using string operations like that. Create an array and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: Certainly the answer to your question is: the code can be modified to write to a text file instead of sending to elastic. But I somehow doubt that is your real question...

Comment: What problem are you having converting it like that? Use `file_put_contents()` to write a string to a file.

Comment: `$bulk_json` is not valid JSON. All the objects need to be elements of an array, and they need to be separated by commas.

Comment: yeah, I guess I should have been more specific with what i wanted to get here, my first post, excuse the newbness please

Comment: Why are you sending to elastic twice?

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_put_contents()`. Replace the call to `send_to_elastic()` with:

```
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $bulk_json);
```

You should also generate the JSON correctly, something like:

```
$result = array();
foreach($group_sets AS $group_set) {
    $result[] = ["index" => [ "_id" => $group_set['our_sku']]];
    $result[] = $group_set; 
}  
foreach($remove_skus AS $sku) {
    $result[] = [ "delete" => [ "_id" => $sku ]];         
}
$bulk_json = json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly would I add that and what would I comment out so it doesnt send to what it does now?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you do this instead of calling `send_to_elastic()`?

Comment: how do i post here what my modified code looks like? Adding a comment doesn't work for that.

Comment: Edit the question and add the new code at the bottom. Don't remove the original code.

Comment: I added the modified code. Btw, searchresults.txt has perms of 777, but nothing gets written to it.